# Using PHP to write colons to XML

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I am trying to output an XML file from PhP using SimpleXML. I have run into problems with the ":" (colon) character. (Talk about art imitating life!)

**Is there any way to escape the colon so I can add my elements to the object?**

Here is my code:

```
$urlset->addAttribute('xmlns','http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9');
```

This line passes okay, so it is only the attribute name that is failing, as in the below examples:

```
$urlset->addAttribute('xmlns:xsi','http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance');
$urlset->addAttribute('xsi:schemaLocation','http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd');
```

In each case, it lops off anything preceding the ":", like so:

```
<urlset 
    xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" 
    xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd"
>
```

Again, my problem is not with reading/parsing the ":" from XML, but with writing the ":" to XML from PHP. There is lots on parsing on the 'net, but I've found nothing on writing a ":" from PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you can't use SimpleXML to *define* the namespaces that are going to be used in the document (which is what the `xmlns` attributes do).  I've found that you can simply specify them in the declaration of your root node like this:

```
$simpleXml = new SimpleXMLElement('<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9 http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9/sitemap.xsd"></urlset>');
```

In your case of building a sitemap, you probably won't have to worry about setting any namespaces beyond that.  However, for a more generic solution, this defines a default namespace and a second namespace with the prefix `alt`.

```
$simpleXml = new SimpleXMLElement('<root xmlns="http://default.namespace.com" xmlns:alt="http://alt.namespace.com"></root>');

$simpleXml->addChild("child", "node in the default namespace");
$simpleXml->addChild("other", "node in the alternate namespace", "http://alt.namespace.com");

print $simpleXml->asXML();
```

will yield:

```
<root xmlns="http://default.namespace.com" xmlns:alt="http://alt.namespace.com">
  <child>node in the default namespace</child>
  <alt:other>node in the alternate namespace</alt:other>
</root>
```

The third optional argument to `addAttribute` is the namespace which can help you create attributes or nodes with that name space.  Note that you need to use the *url* of the namespace (not the prefix).

Comment: I'm getting a bit further with your info here, but I have to book for the night. I promise I will follow up tomorrow. Thank you.

Comment: Your method did not work, but this one did: ````$xml->addAttribute('xmlns:xmlns:xsi', 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance');```` Note the two colons. @notesville Any thoughts as to the difference?

Comment: @Parapluie indeed you're correct, it appears you can't defined namespaces using SimpleXML.  I've updated my answer above which hopefully helps...

Comment: Thank you for taking on the brave mantle of mentorship, @notesville. I'm ashamed at my lack of XML knowledge. When I finally devote some time to study it, I will be re-visiting this excellent SO answer. All the best!